# How to show a running total in a DevExpress PivotGrid?

Tags: delphi, grid, devexpress

I need to show totals like the total plus the last total in a DevExpress PivotGrid.
Example:
Taking this values:
 March: 25
 April: 10
 May: 30

Resulting in this:

```
March   April  May
25      35     65
```

How do I configure my PivotGrid to this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the Field's [RunningTotal](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraPivotGridPivotGridFieldBase_RunningTotaltopic) property to true.

Comment: OK, but I have an earlier version than that wich has this property available, then I need to implement this function manually.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this code in the field's OnCalculateCustomSummary event:

```
procedure TMyForm.cxDBPivotGrid1Field2CalculateCustomSummary(Sender: TcxPivotGridField; ASummary: TcxPivotGridCrossCellSummary);
var
  AColumn: TcxPivotGridGroupItem;
  APrevCrossCell: TcxPivotGridCrossCell;
  APrevCrossCellSummary: TcxPivotGridCrossCellSummary;
begin
  inherited;
  AColumn := ASummary.Owner.Column;
  if (AColumn.Level = -1) then
    // column grand totals
    ASummary.Custom := ASummary.Sum
  else begin
    // all cells, except for column grand totals
    // getting a custom summary calculated for the previous grouping value
    if AColumn.PrevSibling <> nil then begin
      APrevCrossCell        := AColumn.PrevSibling.GetCellByCrossItem(ASummary.Owner.Row);
      APrevCrossCellSummary := APrevCrossCell.SummaryCells[Sender.SummaryIndex];
      ASummary.Custom       := VarToDouble(APrevCrossCellSummary.Custom) + VarToDouble(ASummary.Sum);
    end
    else
      ASummary.Custom       := ASummary.Sum;
  end;
end;
```

And this in the field's OnGetDisplayText event:

```
procedure TForm1.cxDBPivotGrid1Field2GetDisplayText(Sender: TcxPivotGridField; ACell: TcxPivotGridDataCellViewInfo; var AText: string);
begin
  inherited;
  AText := VarToStr(ACell.CellSummary.Custom)
end;
```

Extracted from:
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q90021.aspx